# Analyzing the Web API Traffic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have custom Web API been hosted and exposed. I want to know how to get details like who accessed my Web API, time of accessing,etc. In short I just want to know my Web API usage history.
Can it be possible? If so, can you please help me in this context for where to look and so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler to accomplish logging. As a start, have a look at the following blogs:

[Log message Request and Response in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/09/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx).

[ASP.NET Web Api–Request/Response/Usage Logging](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2012/02/26/asp-net-web-api-request-response-usage-logging.aspx)

and this for an alternative using an `ActionFilter`

[Implementing Audit Trails using ASP.NET MVC ActionFilters](https://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/implementing-audit-trails-using-asp-net-mvc-actionfilters/comment-page-1/)